# How to convert buffered-reader string to JSON in android?

Tags: android, json, bufferedreader

I get json response in Buffered Reader. Now How to convert buffered-reader string to JSON?

I get the String like

```
[
  {
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "password": "test@123!",
    "role": "monitor",
    "code": "0"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JSONArray aardata = new JSONArray(your buffered reader String):
```

And For Parse

```
  JSONObject obj = arrdata.getJsonObject(0);

      String email = obj.getString('email');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create JSONArray with the response string by using:

```
JSONArray arrayJSON = new JSONArray(responseString);
```

And use `getJSONObject()` to get JSONObject and use `getString()` to get string value from particular JSONObject.